# error when i lunch : from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to code a U-net model that will allow me to do image segmentation. When I try to run this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
```

I get this error:

> The Kernel crashed while executing code in the current cell or a previous cell

But I can't solve it.

I've already tried to see other chat but I couldn't solve the problem.

Here are my TensorFlow and Keras versions:

```
tensorflow==2.15.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.15.0
tensorflow-intel==2.15.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.31.0
keras==2.15.0
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
keras-utils==1.0.13
```

Comment: The error message you're encountering, "The Kernel crashed while executing code in the current cell or a previous cell," can arise due to several factors, including incompatible library versions, memory constraints, or conflicts in the environment configuration.Check Library Compatibility:
The versions of TensorFlow and Keras you mentioned (**tensorflow==2.15.0 and keras==2.15.0**) do not seem to be valid versions.Update TensorFlow and Keras:pip install --upgrade tensorflow
pip install --upgrade keras